# RxJs: Subscribe to array of streams which changes dynamically

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

### The problem

I have variable amount of sources streaming data — A, B, C. Sources could be added or removed at any time.

So I create stream of array of such sources D to observe this array.

Then I want to process inner data from this array of sources (for example how their value is being changed over time).

So I transform their state (toPairs) and aggregate this data in subscription for D (see code).

### Expectations

- (ok) **when** I pass new data to A, B, or C, **then** I should see array of changed states (from, to) in subscription for D.
- (ok) **when** I pass same data to A, B, or C, **then** I shouldn't see any output changes.
- (err) **when** I pass any data to A, B, or C and this source is presented in list, **then** I should see just one line in output.
- (err) **when** I pass same sources list to D, **then** I should see the same output as before
- (err) **when** I pass sources list with additional item to D, **then** I should see the same output as before plus changes for that additional item.

### Sample code

```
const Rx = require("rxjs/Rx");
const Promise = require("bluebird");

const A = new Rx.BehaviorSubject("a1");
const B = new Rx.BehaviorSubject("b1");
const C = new Rx.BehaviorSubject("c1");

const DEFAULT_PAIRS = ['??', '??']; // [ <old value>, <new value> ]
const toPairs = ([, oldValue], newValue) => {
  return [oldValue, newValue]
};

const A_ = A.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged().scan(toPairs, DEFAULT_PAIRS);
const B_ = B.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged().scan(toPairs, DEFAULT_PAIRS);
const C_ = C.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged().scan(toPairs, DEFAULT_PAIRS);

const D = new Rx.BehaviorSubject([A_, B_]);

D.asObservable()
  .startWith([])
  .flatMap(streams => {
    return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
      ...streams,
      (...data) => data
    )
  })
  .subscribe(v => {
    console.log(v)
  });

Promise
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change A to new value --'))
  .then(() => A.next("a2"))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change A to new value --'))
  .then(() => A.next("a3"))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change A to the same value --'))
  .then(() => A.next("a3"))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change D to the same array --'))
  .then(() => D.next([A_, B_]))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change B to new value --'))
  .then(() => B.next("b2"))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change C to new value --'))
  .then(() => C.next("c2"))
  .delay(0)
  .then(() => console.log('-- change D to new array --'))
  .then(() => D.next([A_, B_, C_]));
```

### Output from sample code

```
[ [ '??', 'a1' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to new value --
[ [ 'a1', 'a2' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to new value --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to the same value --
-- change D to the same array --
[ [ '??', 'a3' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change B to new value --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ 'b1', 'b2' ] ]
[ [ '??', 'a3' ], [ 'b1', 'b2' ] ]
-- change C to new value --
-- change D to new array --
[ [ '??', 'a3' ], [ '??', 'b2' ], [ '??', 'c2' ] ]
```

### Comments

As you see, every time when I pass any data to D, then I see that previous values are lost in output.

There is also strange thing with "change B to new value" section: it shows 2 outputs. The first line is correct. Then it updates one more time and prints out unexpected line with incorrect content.

### Expected output

```
[ [ '??', 'a1' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to new value --
[ [ 'a1', 'a2' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to new value --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change A to the same value --
-- change D to the same array --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ '??', 'b1' ] ]
-- change B to new value --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ 'b1', 'b2' ] ]
-- change C to new value --
-- change D to new array --
[ [ 'a2', 'a3' ], [ 'b1', 'b2' ], [ 'c1', 'c2' ] ]
```

### Question

How to fix this code in way it will print out expected lines?
Could you propose other solution for such problem?